# Issue installing ImbalancedLearningRegression 0.0.1 package - Metadata error

Tags: python, regression, google-colaboratory, imbalanced-data, smote

I'm encountering difficulties while trying to install the ImbalancedLearningRegression 0.0.1 package. When running the installation command, I receive the following error message:

```
Processing ./ImbalancedLearningRegression-0.0.1.tar.gz
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ImbalancedLearningRegression==0.0.1) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ImbalancedLearningRegression==0.0.1) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ImbalancedLearningRegression==0.0.1) (4.66.2)
Collecting sklearn (from ImbalancedLearningRegression==0.0.1)
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post12.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have tried reinstalling all the necessary dependencies and updating pip, but the issue persists. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you haven't looked into what's wrong in the package yourself, this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: There is [an open pull request to replace `sklearn` with `scikit-learn`](https://github.com/paobranco/ImbalancedLearningRegression/pull/1); maybe try that?

Comment: Thank you for your help! And sorry, I'm new to programming.